# Dns resolution [BIND9] , pinging to the right domain, but answer coming from another domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

I have created my `/etc/network/interfaces`configured like this:
[/etc/network/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhidO.png)

Then I have 2 files i created in `/etc/bind`
One of them is `db.rag.es` , which looks like this: [db.rag.es file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/913V8.png)

And the other one is `db.222.168.192` which looks like this [db.222.168.192 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyce2.png)

Problem is whenever I ping `servidor.rag.es`it returns a proper responde from `(192.168.222.2)`, but if i ping `ftp.rag.es` for some reason it pings to `192.168.22.4`(desired) , but then ive a destination host unreachable coming from `192.168.222.2`when im trying to ping `.4` [ping attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnnZe.png)

Comment: What happens when you ping 192.168.222.4 (not using the name ftp.rag.es)? If you get no response then it is not a DNS problem.

Comment: @DanielK destination host unreachable, apparently not a dns problem then. Its returtning from 192.168.222.2 for some reason

Comment: That is your NIC responding. This is normal.

Comment: @DanielK thanks for the clues, solved it by modifying /etc/network/interfaces by following this https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface

Comment: Do not use `ping` to troubleshoot DNS issues, it is the wrong tool (for almost any troubleshooting in fact). DNS issues are to be troubleshoot using `dig` or a least `nslookup`. Also when asking for help remember to put all relevant information (which could be in your case DNS server configuration and zone content) IN the question (not through a remote link that can become stale) and AS TEXT (to enable copy, search, etc.). Do not bother first with reverse DNS also until you understand how this space is delegated (completely separate from domain names). You have online DNS troubleshooting sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a DNS problem. It is likely a firewall issue.

Comment: I have no firewall in my machine

Comment: In that case its a routing issue. What does your network look like? (Ie how are systems connected, what are the netmasks and routes?)

Comment: its a virtualbox virtualmachine running ubuntu, with the posted network configuration to have a static ipv4. Internal adapter is connected to "Internal network"

Comment: solved it by following https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface to add extra ip addresses

Comment: This is not an answer. It could be any number of things preventing communication, including the firewall

Comment: @DanielK - The point is that it is not a DNS problem, which is what the OP thought and the best answer available wit the given information (and enough to put the OP on the correct path it seems)